# STS with java 1.6 version?

Tags: spring-tool-suite, java-6

I am looking to develop spring boot application with STS using java 1.6, will this be possible with STS. i know that latest STS supports java 1.8 but i want to know whether it works for 1.6 or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STS itself requires a JDK8 to run, but it can be used to implement projects against JDK6 (or even earlier versions). The compiler level and JRE/JDK that you use for your projects is completely decoupled from the JDK that STS uses to run on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, I am working with STS using JDK 1.6 for some reason.

You can download one of legacy versions of STS from [this site](https://spring.io/tools3/sts/legacy)

If you want to create a spring starter project, the version of STS should be a 3.6.4 (The previous versions will not working).

You can add the jdk path of the STS.ini in the install directory.

```
-vm
where-to-jdk-path\jdk1.6\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```